# How to prevent MySQL selecting one index when a better one is available?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a table with 30,000 rows (and growing), which I join with another table. One some pages, I need to run a some 100+ of those queries, and things get slow. If I `EXPLAIN` the query, I notice that one table uses a primary key and is fast, but another table using one of its indexes, which is not the best one. Here's an overview:

`SIMPLE | acc_entries   | ref | ledger,date,type,status,status_ledger_date_type | type | 1 | const   | 15359 | Using where`

This is a sample query:

```
SELECT SUM(usd) AS total FROM acc_entries
LEFT JOIN acc_ledgers ON acc_entries.ledger = acc_ledgers.id
WHERE acc_entries.status = 1 AND 
acc_ledgers.account = 3004 AND 
date >= '2011-01-01' AND 
date <= '2011-08-30' AND 
type = 'credit'
```

As you can see, I am using in my WHERE the fields `status`, `ledger` (which is the field that joins with `acc_ledgers.account`), `date` and `type`. All of these fields have indexes. However, there is also a specific index that is used for all of them, in that same order. It is called `status_ledger_data_type`, and as you can see it is one of the indexes that MySQL considers using. However, at the end MySQL opts to use `type` as an index. This has some 15,000 possible rows (half of the table), whereas the other combined index only features a fraction of this. So my questions is: why does MySQL selects this index when a better one is available, and how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using index hints to force the use of your desired index.

[MySql docs on Index Hints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html)

[The Battle Between Force Index and the Query Optimizer](http://www.mysqldiary.com/the-battle-between-force-index-and-the-query-optimizer/)

[7 ways to convince MySQL to use the right index](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/7-ways-to-convince-mysql-to-use-the-right-index)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you want your index based on your smaller granularity.  The Ledger from your Acc_Entries table will join to your ACC_Ledgers table on ITS primary index of ID, so the Acc_Ledgers is not really utilizing the Ledger portion for the WHERE clause.  Your index should match as closely to the WHERE clause of your common queries.  In this case, I would have an index on

(Account, Status, Type, Date)

The reason for Account being first, smaller result set.  You could have 5,000 entries.  Of those, 300 entries for the one account accounts, so you've already eliminated a huge amount of data to go through.  Then, the Status... of the 300, you could have 100 @ status 1, 100 @ status 2, 100 @ status 3, so you've now reduced the set even more, etc by other criteria of type and date.

Your query otherwise is completely fine... just a personal style in writing, I try to write my queries with the WHERE conditions as closely matching the index in same sequence too, so I would just have the Account clause first, then Status, Type and Date... but again, thats a personal style in writing queries.